# How can I avoid duplicating code inside a for + if chain?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I avoid splitting the code in two separate parts?
I am trying to call the "DoSomething_..." function just once but work in both scenarios.
I might add more "for(s)" to this and the problem is that I have to handle to separate parts of code.

```
    for first in FIRST_LIST:
      for second in SECOND_LIST:
          for third in THIRD_LIST:
              if third!='Some specific thing':
                  for fourth in FOURTH_LIST:
                      DoSomething_K_x_fourth_Times(first,second,third,fourth)
              else:
                  forth=0
                  DoSomething_K_Times(first,second,third,fourth)
```

Comment: `for forth in FORTH_LIST if third != 'Some specific thing' else [0]:`

Comment: The ordinal for four is usually spelled “fourth”, not “forth”. “Forth” is a word that means something different, along the lines of “moving forward”.

Comment: @jasonharper will else[0] branch execute DoSomething_... at all?

Comment: @jasonharper’s suggestion uses Python’s [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). The expression `FORTH_LIST if third != 'Some specific thing' else [0]` means “If `third != 'Some specific thing'`, then use `FORTH_LIST`, otherwise use `[0]`”. Either way it’s iterating over that list.

Comment: @Daniel H thank you! I updated

Comment: `itertools.product()` could save you some nesting

Comment: @Chris_Rands will itertools.product(FIRST_LIST,SECOND_LIST,THIRD_LIST) do the same as nested for(s)?

Comment: @CezC, `for first, second, third in itertools.product(FIRST_LIST, SECOND_LIST, THIRD_LIST): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list with single item `[0]` or `FOURTH_LIST` depending on the condition, and iterate the list:

```
for first in FIRST_LIST:
    for second in SECOND_LIST:
        for third in THIRD_LIST:
            if third == 'Some specific thing':
                a_list = [0]
            else:
                a_list = FOURTH_LIST
            for fourth in a_list:
                DoSomething_K_x_fourth_Times(first, second, third, fourth)
```

**UPDATE**

Assign different function to a variable (`func` in the below code) depending on the condition, and call the function.

```
for first in FIRST_LIST:
    for second in SECOND_LIST:
        for third in THIRD_LIST:
            if third == 'Some specific thing':
                a_list = [0]
                func = DoSomething_K_x_fourth_Times
            else:
                a_list = FOURTH_LIST
                func = DoSomething_K_Times

            for fourth in a_list:
                func(first, second, third, fourth)
```

Comment: But it’s a different function being called, and you never reset `FORTH_LIST` to what it was before.

Comment: @DanielH, Ah, I missed it. I will update the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You are still overwritting `FOURTH_LIST` with `[0]`.

Comment: The function should do the same thing, I gave it two different names only to point out that the number of function calls vary: if third == 'Some specific thing' the function should only be called K times (K=len(FIRST_LIST)*len(SECOND_LIST)*len(THIRD_LIST)) also in this case FOURTH_LIST does not matter; but when third != 'Some specific thing', I need to take into account FOURTH_LIST and call my function ( len(FIRST_LIST)*len(SECOND_LIST)*len(THIRD_LIST)*len(FOURTH_LIST) )times.

Comment: @VPfB, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer to use new variable.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you very much! It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
  def DoSomething_K_Times(first,second,third,splitpoint):
      for x in splitpoint:
          ...

  for first in FIRST_LIST:
      for second in SECOND_LIST:
          for third in THIRD_LIST:
              if third != 'Some specific thing':
                  DoSomething_K_Times(first,second,third,FOURTH_LIST)
              else:
                  DoSomething_K_Times(first,second,third,[0])
```

Comment: I don't understand why would I define a function multiple times.

Comment: @CezC you are right, it is not necessary. code have been edited